# Do the Orange Stars indicating a legendary drop appear on the quick (TAB) map?

Tags: diablo-iii

Last night in a bounty run, I quickly had to return to town because my inventory was full, and when I portaled back to my group, I saw that a legendary had dropped in an area where my group had cleared without me on my mini-map. **I did not think to check the Tab map to see if it would appear there.** I would hate to miss out on a Legendary drop, but also hate to hold up my group while I comb through any areas they already hit!

If someone can confirm that this icon **would appear on the larger map that appears when holding the TAB key on my keyboard** from their experience, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Last time I checked, all of the markers that appear on the minimap also appear on the tab map overlay. So I would expect this one would too.

Edit: Source: http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/31191-officially-impossible-to-miss-legendaries-now

Confirmed they do show up so people don't miss them.

Comment: I know that the orange star indicates a legendary has dropped. I also know that it will appear on my minimap. What I want to know is, if I hit the TAB key on my keyboard to bring up the full map overlay, will the Star also appear there?

Comment: Last time I checked, all of the markers that appear on the minimap also appear on the tab map overlay.  So I would expect this one would too.  Usually I pick them up as soon as I see them but if I get to it before you do, I'll test it out and post back once I get a legendary drop.  I'm almost positive it does though.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to reflect this please? So it is clearer for other users.

Comment: Edited the answer with a source.